# Opening a text file in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, file, permission-denied

I'm not sure if this has been answered already but I did look and can't find any.

My teammates does not have access to a file via this path: `\\SYDSFILES01\Product\MNL\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\`. They have access to all files within the MNL folder but cannot access `\\sydsfiles01\product\`. What we did is to map the folder ending up with `N:\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\`.

However, when I run the below, it results to an error as the program tries to locate the file via `\\SYDSFILES01\Product\MNL\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\`. I tried some workaround but to no avail. I hope you could help. The script being run is within `N:\SellOutQC\`

```
def import_weekly():
    import csv
    import os
    file = "/PythonScripts/parameters.txt"
    path = os.getcwd()+file

    d={}
    with open(path, 'r+') as file:
        for i in csv.reader(file,delimiter='\t'):
            d[i[0]]=i[1]
    return d

Error: 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\sydsfiles01\\product\\manila\\selloutqc\\pythonscripts\\Parameters.txt'
```

Comment: You want  to access a file you don't have access to?

Comment: Change file permissions

Comment: `My teammates does not have access to a file via absolute path`, so you have? You run it? Why teammates come to this question?

Comment: We do have access to it, just not directly. Sorry, here's how it actually looks like: \\SYDSFILES01\Product\MNL\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\Parameters.txt

The team cannot access this path directly, only the MNL folder and so we ended up mapping \\SYDSFILES01\Manila\ as N:/. They can access everything within this folder but when used in the script, it reads file by \\SYDSFILES01\Product\Manila\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\Parameters.txt, not the mapped folder ie N:\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\Parameters.txt

Comment: Perhaps, you don't have `write` access to that file. Change the access mode from `r+` to `r`. then try.

Comment: We do. We can edit the actual file. We wanted the program to access the file via the mapped path instead of the original path as the members don't have access to \\sydsfiles01\product\ which is what the script above uses to locate the file.

Comment: Is the code working if you hard code `N:\SellOutQC\ ` instead of `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: "Mapped" how? Is this mapping available to Python and active in the context where you run this script?

Comment: You should print (as debugging info) the result of `os.getcwd()`

Comment: That is weird. I tried to map a subdir of a network share with `net use x: \\server\path\to\folder` then I opened Python from a console window at `X:\ `. In Python, `os.getcwd()` shows as expected `X:\ `. How have you *mapped* the remote folder?

Comment: Hi Serge! We mapped '\\SYDSFILES01\MNL' as 'N:\' since we cannot acccess '\\SYDSFILES01\Product\' If we try to map '\\SYDSFILES01\Product\MNL' it result to an error.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code is working with the hardcoded path `r'N:\SellOutQC\PythonScripts\Parameters.txt'`, you can use `os.popen('cd').readline().strip('\n')` to read the mapped location of current working directory on Windows system instead of `os.getcwd()`. e.g.

`mapped_path = os.popen("cd").readline().strip('\n')`

The `print(mapped_path)` should print `N:\\SellOutQC` in your case.

Comment: Hi Kumar! I haven't been able to try the hardcoded path yet but will do so in a while and will let you know if it works. Thank you so much!